# How to use WlanRegisterNotification function

Tags: c++, wifi, wlanapi

I want to register wlan notification.

**Code:**

```
HANDLE hClient;
DWORD dwResult = 0;
DWORD dwPrevNotif = 0;

dwResult = WlanRegisterNotification(hClient, WLAN_NOTIFICATION_SOURCE_ALL, TRUE, NotificationCallback, NULL, NULL, &dwPrevNotif);

void WINAPI WirelessConnect::NotificationCallback(PWLAN_NOTIFICATION_DATA wlanData, PVOID context)
{

}
```

The problem is:

`error: C3867: 'WirelessConnect::NotificationCallback': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member`

When I use `&NotificationCallback` I get error:

`error: C2276: '&': illegal operation on bound member function expression`

How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: That issues isn't much related to `WlanRegisterNotification()` but a more general problem. Improve your question title please. Also show the declaration of your class please. Is `NotificationCallback` declared as `static` class member?

Comment: @user0042

No, it's not static - void WINAPI NotificationCallback(PWLAN_NOTIFICATION_DATA wlanData, PVOID context);

I use Qt.

Comment: So you need to make it a `static` member function to fix the problem.

Comment: @user0042 

Yes, it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to pass a pointer to a member function as a callback, that is - as a function pointer. You shouldn't do that, member function pointers are meaningless without the object itself.

You should make your callback a static function, that way there are no objects involved.